# Insert To Column In Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am getting a HTTP call to Laravel and I want to take my data that is coming in and insert it into a column of my table. Here is my code:

`$data = Input::all();` This is my data coming from HTTP

`$user = User::find($data['user_id']);` This is finding the user out of my user table in mySQL DB.

```js
+----+------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+
| id | account_id | email  | first_name | last_name | token | fb_id | created_at | updated_at | location | fb_token | deleted_at | access_code | is_account_admin | password | username    | deleted_with_location | is_video_enabled | device_token |
+----+------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+
```

So I want to insert `$data['deviceToken']` into the `deviceToken` column of this table.

How can I do this on my Laravel controller?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to create new user or update existing one?

Comment: Because device token col existed in dtb. So what you need to do is. $user->deviceToken = $data['deviceToken']; $user->save()

Comment: Please make this an answer below and I will accept it! Perfection.

Comment: @austin: ok , done

Comment: Can you vote up for me, austin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because device token col existed in dtb. So what you need to do is.

```
    ` $user->deviceToken = $data['deviceToken']; 
    $user->save();`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user->update(['deviceToken'=>$data['deviceToken']]);
```

As easy as that

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you can insert data to a column
1. Use model save() method.

```
$user = User::find($data['user_id']);
$user->column_want_to_insert = $value;
ex: $user->deviceToken = $data['deviceToken']; $user->save();
```

2.Use DB update() method.

```
$update = User::where('id',$data['user_id'])->update([
  'deviceToken' => $data['deviceToken']
]);
```

but if you use this way the 'deviceToken' field has to in $fillable property in User model